# Change in state do not propagate in props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the "classic" issue with the React redux about not propagating the change in `state` into the `props` when I try to access it in the component.

[Here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/2190) I have read that

> 99.9% of the time, this is because you are accidentally mutating data, usually in your reducer

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? Is this the good way how to do the deep copy of the property of the specified object in array?

note: in the reducer in the return statement the state is clearly changed correctly (debugged it)

**reducer:**

```
case 'TOGGLE_SELECTED_TAG':
        const toggledTagId = action.payload;

        const index = findItemById(state.tags, toggledTagId);
        const newTags = state.tags.slice(0);
        if(index >= 0)
        {
            newTags[index] = Object.assign(
                state.tags[index], 
                {selected: !state.tags[index].selected});

            state.tags = newTags;
        }

        return Object.assign({}, state);
```

**component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, FormControl, Table, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';

import {selectTagAction} from '../../actions/actions'

@connect((store) => {
return {
    tags: store.TagsReducer.tags,
}
})

export default class AssignTag extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleTagClick = this.handleTagClick.bind(this);
}

handleTagClick(element) {
    debugger;
    this.props.dispatch(selectTagAction(element));
}

 render() {
    const tags = this.props.tags;
    console.log(tags);
    const mappedTags = tags.map(tag => {
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-12" key={tag.id} onClick={() => this.handleTagClick(tag.id)}
                style={{background: this.getBackgroundColor(tag.selected)}}>
                <span>{tag.name}</span>
            </div>
        )
    })

// code continues
}
```

}

Comment: What is this statement doing? `const newTags = state.tags.slice(0);`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: can you update the code to show the full reducer ? Including the function header ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed mutating the state. Try this:

```
case 'TOGGLE_SELECTED_TAG':
        const toggledTagId = action.payload;
        const index = findItemById(state.tags, toggledTagId);
        let newTags = state;
        if( index >= 0 )
        {
            newTags[index] = Object.assign(
                {},
                state.tags[index],
                { selected: !state.tags[index].selected }
              );
            //state.tags = newTags;   This line essentially mutates the state
            return Object.assign( {}, state, { tags: newTags });
        }

        return state;
```

Comment: your code works if I change `let newTags;` with `const newTags = state.tags.slice(0);`. can you please describe more why the line is mutating the state?

Comment: not that line. the line `state.tags = newTags` is the line mutating the state, by changing value of one of its keys.

Comment: what I meant is your code is not working throwing an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` therefore I modified your line `let newTags;` with `const newTags = state.tags.slice(0);`. now it works. Also you were right about the line when I am mutating the state

Comment: Ok sorry. Forgot that. And you needn't `slice` the state. You can copy it as it is `let newTags = state;`. As long as you don't mutate the state it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround to avoiding mutation of state is to use the ES6 shorthand in your reducer:

```
....   return { ...state, tags : newTags };
```